# logrotate in centos does not rotate logs

Tags: logrotate, centos8

Running centos 8 and have `logrotate` to rotate my logs for nginx. The logs rotate as expected if I run the command manually using `"logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.conf`", but do not run when  the `cron` job runs. I have validated that the `cronjob` is running by viewing the `/var/log/cron` log file as shown

```
Oct 26 15:55:01 c22fin2 run-parts[916513]: (/etc/cron.hourly) starting 0anacron
Oct 26 15:55:01 c22fin2 anacron[916522]: Anacron started on 2023-10-26
Oct 26 15:55:01 c22fin2 anacron[916522]: Will run job `cron.daily' in 0 min.
Oct 26 15:55:01 c22fin2 anacron[916522]: Jobs will be executed sequentially
Oct 26 15:55:01 c22fin2 anacron[916522]: Job `cron.daily' started
Oct 26 15:55:01 c22fin2 run-parts[916513]: (/etc/cron.hourly) finished 0anacron
Oct 26 15:55:01 c22fin2 run-parts[916524]: (/etc/cron.daily) starting logrotate
Oct 26 15:55:01 c22fin2 run-parts[916524]: (/etc/cron.daily) finished logrotate
Oct 26 15:55:01 c22fin2 anacron[916522]: Job `cron.daily' terminated (produced output)
Oct 26 15:55:01 c22fin2 anacron[916522]: Normal exit (1 job run)
```

The status is updated for the file in the `/var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status` file as well. There seems to be no indication of an issue?

Comment: If you have selinux active (you should) try relabelling log files `restorecon -rv /var/log` and see if it helps.

Comment: That did not fix it, although, the logs files for nginx are stored under /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs, not /var/logs

Comment: This probably means that you compiled nginx yourself and are using non-standard (per distro and distro-included nginx package) locations. This may trigger selinux denials. Try disabling selinux (`setenforce 0`) and see if this helps.

Comment: I fixed it by adding it as a log location. thanks! Commands are: 
semanage fcontext -a -t var_log_t <directory/logfile>
restorecon -v <directory/logfile>

Comment: Add it as an answer and mark as accepted for others to see.